# How can I remove all matched parts from string?

Tags: php, regex, loops

Here is my code:

```
$tags_specified_pattern = "/\[(.+?)\]/";
preg_match_all($tags_specified_pattern, $q, $matches);
if ( count($matches[1]) ){
    I need to remove all matched parts form $q
}
```

---

Here is an example:

```
$q = "This is [tag1] tag1 and this is [tag2] tag2";
```

And this is the expected result:

```
This is tag1 and this is tag2
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: `preg_replace`em with `''`

Comment: So, `$q = preg_replace($tags_specified_pattern, '$1', $q);`, what is the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The problem is `preg_mach` has an `all` version. `preg_match_all`. But `preg_replace` hasn't.

Comment: @MartinAJ `preg_replace` replaces all match occurrences by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_replace**

```
<?php
$pattern = '/\\[(.+?)\\]/';
$replacement = '';
$subject = 'This is [tag1] tag1 and this is [tag2] tag2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1 );
?>
```

Comment: The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1.